# Is it possible to workaround wrong transitive dependency in Maven?

Tags: maven, transitive-dependency

We use JPod library in our program. Now I'm trying to switch it to Maven, so I added these lines to the `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>de.intarsys.opensource</groupId>
  <artifactId>jPod</artifactId>
  <version>5.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

However, after this Maven build fails with the following message:

> The following artifacts could not be resolved: javax.media:jai-core:jar:1.1.3, com.sun.media:jai-codec:jar:1.1.3: Failure to find javax.media:jai-core:jar:1.1.3 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

The problem is that JPod depends on some libraries, which list their dependencies as jai-core and jai-codec. However, there are no such artifacts, instead there are jai_core and jai_codec (with underscore instead of hyphen). I don't know, maybe they were renamed at some point.

You can see what I mean [on this page](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.intarsys.opensource/iscwt/5.5): just click on link to jai-core in "Depends on" section.

Is there some way how I can "override" such broken dependencies? Or how would I proceed here at all? I'm generally unfamiliar with Maven, so a detailed answer would be better.

Comment: You could try an explicit exclude and manually include the correct dependencies.

Comment: This will not solve your problem but I'd like to point out that the jPod version in Central is quite old and you might be better off just downloading the libs from Sourceforge and creating your own POMs for them. Also see here: https://sourceforge.net/p/jpodlib/support-requests/4/

Comment: @user2543253: Oh, thanks. Actually, we use it only to extract text from PDF documents for indexing purposes and we currently use even older 5.2 version. If they don't support Maven, I think I'll check if I can keep this library just as jars, i.e. untracked by Maven dependency system.